# Raw socket program on android

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I have created a raw socket program in c and calling this from jni. it compiles but doesnt build. no errors in fact. but a warning  "No JNI_OnLoad found".

Pls let me know about this.

Is it becoz of raw socket.? how to know to error?

Comment: The only way you'll be able to use raw sockets on Android is if you root the device and run a separate binary. It won't work within your app, since your app isn't running as root.

Answer (score 1):

"No JNI_OnLoad found"

Is actually not an error or atypical condition at all.  It's a mild warning that unfortunately appears more important than it is - all it means is that your JNI library doesn't take advantage of the ability to have an intialization function that is automatically called when the library is loaded.

However, it is unclear if your application will be able to obtain permission to use raw sockets on Android - I would have thought it could not.